# How to force elements to have the same relative position in any screen?

Tags: css, css-position, mask

What is the best way to reproduce this effect

[image]

in any resolution? Is there any way to force this elements (header, content area, menu items and footer) to always have the same relative position to each other, so that they stay always perfectly aligned without ever breaking the curved effect, or should I go for a CSS mask?

So far all the elements are images, except the text.

Comment: may be you need absolute positioning of header/footer with respect to outer container which have 100% height.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. To have an element always appear in the centre, add to its css

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

As to the footer, first make a background div (with your image set as background) with

```
width: 100%;
```

And inside of it put a div with again:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

And then put all these divs and images in the main container with

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
```

From my experience, it is always better to use margins, paddings and fixed widths than relative or fixed positioning when working on a layout.